# Touchscreen friendly file picker in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-10, fileopenpicker

I am looking for a touchscreen-friendly file picker for Windows 10. In Windows 8 and 8.1, i used FileOpenPicker:

```
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;

IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await fileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
```

which produced a nice interface ([example](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC600568.png)), but in Windows 10, the same code displays the same interface as OpenFileDialog would ([example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/images/vb.net_openfile_dialog1.jpg)), which is very hard to use on a touchscreen. Does anyone know how to get Windows 8/8.1 style FileOpenPicker in Windows 10, or knows an alternative?

Comment: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-tablet-mode-windows-10

Comment: I tried Tablet mode before asking here... The app runs in full screen, but it has no effect on the open file dialog.

Comment: Looks like it was reported back in Dec 2014 on pre-release build too: http://mcakins.com/2014/12/03/file-picker-changes-in-windows-10-build-9879/

Comment: @ArtiFicial, I believe that this is just the current way it is in Windows 10, possibly to remove the confusion between desktop and UWP apps. Hopefully we will see this changed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In my application I have ask user to select folder (with standard folder picker that is not much touch friendly), but after this I have shown my own custom control that have display files in folder and let them select in touch friendly manner.